# How to Reset dropdown value on "clear search"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, coffeescript

I have a drop down in a search form and a clear search button. I want the selected values in the dropdown to be cleared upon clicking on the button. The coffeescript code included below all works except I cannot get the dropdown to clear. How can I do this?

```
<%= search_form_for @search, :builder => SimpleForm::FormBuilder do |f|%>
  <%= f.input :year_gteq, :collection =>years_options%>

  <%= f.input :year_lteq, :collection =>years_options%>

<%= f.submit "Clear Search", :name => nil, :id => :q_reset, :class => "btn" %>
```

coffee script

```
$("#q_reset").click ->
    $(".clear-fields").val('')
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked')
    $('#clear-dropdown-fields').prop('selectedIndex', 0)
```

This is what worked for me:

$('form select').val('')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same id for 2 dom elements which is the reason why

```
$('#clear-dropdown-fields').prop('selectedIndex', 0)
```

wont work on the second dropdown.  What you can do is to use a class instead of id or just find the elements inside the form.  You can also use `val('')` to reset the value.

```
$('form select').val('')
```

Comment: I changed it to  $('.clear-dropdown-fields').prop('selectedIndex', 0) it's not working still.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `reset()` on the form to return the fields to their starting value.

Or you could set `selectedIndex` to `0`.

```
$('#clear-dropdown-fields').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately neither is working for me... any idea why?